# Pyspark Streaming application stucks during a batch processing

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have a pyspark applicataion that loads data from Kinesis and saves to S3.

Each batch processing time is quite stable, but then it can stuck.
How can I figure out why it happens?

Code sample:

```
columns = [x.name for x in schema]
Event = Row(*[x[0] for x in columns])


def get_spark_session_instance(sparkConf):
    if ("sparkSessionSingletonInstance" not in globals()):
        globals()["sparkSessionSingletonInstance"] = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .config(conf=sparkConf) \
            .getOrCreate()
    return globals()["sparkSessionSingletonInstance"]


def creating_func():
    def timing(message):
        print('timing', str(datetime.utcnow()), message)

    def process_game(df, game, time_part):

        # s3
        df.write.json("{}/{}/{}/{}".format(path_prefix, game, 'group_1', time_part),
                      compression="gzip", timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        timing('{}_grop_1'.format(game))

        df[df['group'] == 2] \
            .write.json("{}/{}/{}/{}".format(path_prefix, game, 'group_2', time_part),
                        compression="gzip", timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        timing('{}_grop_2'.format(game))

        # database
        df[df['group'] == 3].select(*db_columns) \
            .write.jdbc(db_connection_string, table="test.{}group_3".format(game), mode='append',
                        properties=db_connection_propetries)
        timing('{}_db'.format(game))

    def event_to_row(event):
        event_dict = json.loads(event)
        event_dict['json_data'] = event_dict.get('json_data') and json.dumps(
            event_dict.get('json_data'))
        return Event(*[event_dict.get(x) for x in columns])

    def process(rdd):
        if not rdd.isEmpty():

            spark_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M%S_%f')

            rows_rdd = rdd.map(event_to_row)
            spark = get_spark_session_instance(rdd.context.getConf())
            df = spark.createDataFrame(data=rows_rdd, schema=schema)
            df = df.withColumn("ts", df["ts"].cast(TimestampType())) \
                .withColumn("processing_time", lit(datetime.utcnow()))

            df.cache()

            print('timing -----------------------------')

            process_game(df[df['app_id'] == 1], 'app_1', spark_time)
            process_game(df[df['app_id'] == 2], 'app_2', spark_time)

    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 240)
    kinesis_stream = KinesisUtils.createStream(
        ssc, sys.argv[2], 'My-stream-name', "kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        'us-east-1', InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON, 240, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)

    kinesis_stream.repartition(16 * 3).foreachRDD(process)

    ssc.checkpoint(checkpoint_prefix + sys.argv[1])
    return ssc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('timing', 'cast ts', str(datetime.utcnow()))

    ssc = StreamingContext.getActiveOrCreate(checkpoint_prefix + sys.argv[1], creating_func)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

[Streaming Web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkzAO.png)
[Batches info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPHmN.png)

Comment: Looks like one worker is frozen. Because my S3 folder has less files than should for this batch and no _SUCCESS file

Answer (score 0):

identify the process taking the time, use kill -QUIT or jstack to get the stack trace. look in the source for possible delays, and consider where you can increase log4j logging for more info.

Does the delay increase with the amount of data written? If so, that's the usual "rename is really copy" problem s3 has

Comment: > Does the delay increase with the amount of data written?

Normal execution time is 40 seconds, but when it hangs it can be frozen on whole night and never seen it unfreeze.

Comment: something else then. Time to get into stack trace-based debugging I'm afraid